# VB DataGrid - When row is selected

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I'm working on a project for a mobile device, using VB framework 2.0. The "DataGridView" is not avalible - it's the DataGrid I'm using.

Now I want to know how to do something when a row is selected. I'm trying to do somethink like this:

```
Private Sub MyGrid_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyGrid.CurrentCellChanged
    SelectedRow()
End Sub
Private Sub SelectedRow()
    Dim SelectedRow As Integer = MyGrid.CurrentRowIndex
    Dim numCellsSelected As Integer = 'How do i count the number of selected cells in the row above?
    If *numCellsSelected on SelectedRow* = 5 Then '5 is the number of cells
        MsgBox ("Row " & SelectedRow & " is selected!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I on the right track, and/or how do I do this?